# Set values to textview in Toast programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I need to access inner textview via layout inflater

sudo hirarchy:

```
<relative layout id="rlRoot">
 <relative layout>
  <linear layout>
   <linear layout>
    <relative layout id="rlTv">
      <textView id="tvOne">
```

I want to dynamically set value for the id tvOne through toast.

Logic I used as below

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rlRoot));
TextView txtId = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvOne);
txtId.setText("Id: " + getId());

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());

toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

But this gives "View not attached to window manager". 
I also changed rlRoot to rlTv. But same error.
How can I access this nested text view?

Comment: Yes, it is not a problem with context I guess. Actually above that textView I also have a button which I set to invisible in code after I call setText function on that textView.
After I set inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null) seems logic is working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your logic is in your `onCreate()` then change

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rlRoot));
```

This line to

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
```

Like this. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Actually it is not in onCreate but a separate function. But as I mentioned in ρяσѕρєя K's comment by setting it to null, it worked. I think if we specify a viewGroup, we need to travel exact parent as I originally asked in this question. But if it is null, it by default decides the root of the inflated xml as in specification. Anyway thanks for your anwser.